# Case status not getting updated through Flow Builder

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have 1 custom object and 1 standard object on which the flow is implemented. Whenever the status of the custom object is changed, Case status field also needs to be changed. I have created a record triggered flow on the custom object by selecting the following option [image]

So, this how the flow works, the moment there is a status update on the custom object, the status on the case object should will also be changed. I have put a decision on the flow which checks for the status on the custom object. The moment there is a change in the status, the corresponding status is updated on the case.

I have tried testing this scenario, even though the status changed on the custom object, but somehow the case status is not updated with the flow.

Can someone let me know where it is causing an issue?

This is the flow: [image]

Comment: Please review [ask] and [help/on-topic], then [edit] your post to provide all of the details of your current implementation and how to reproduce the issue. It's impossible for anyone to help you with out more information.

Comment: Hi David, I have updated my question accordingly. Pardon me for my previous vague question.

Comment: @JayaHarshit, add an assignment with the desired value for each of the decision path, right before the update.

Comment: please use [edit] and show the details behind the Update Records elements

Answer (score 0):

In the decision check if the status is changed (or Old value!= new value).
In the update block make sure you map caseId and status field, status field will be mapped by the custom object's status field.